# How can I generate a code coverage report with Visual Studio 2012 and NUnit command line tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nunit, code-coverage

Using Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) and NUnit 2.6.2, how can I analyze coverage when running NUnit (nunit-console) on the command line? It seems that Visual Studio is able to analyze coverage when NUnit runs tests within Visual Studio, but I need to know how to do this on the command line as well.

Comment: I believe there is a codecoverage.exe that can be executed on the command line however I have not used it to comment further. I use opensource tools on the command line (build environment) such as OpenCover and PartCover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out how to do this. Turns out there's this commandline utility [vstest.console.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155796.aspx) that's also able to run 3rdparty unit tests, if it has the right adapter(s). Since I've installed the NUnit Test Adapter as an extension to Visual Studio, I must use the `/UseVsixExtensions` option to vstest.console.exe. Additonally, to enable code coverage analysis I supply the `/EnableCodeCoverage` option.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /UseVsixExtensions:true /EnableCodeCoverage "C:\Users\Arve\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.Tests\bin\Debug\MyApp.Tests.dll"
```

The above command produces a a file with the suffix .coverage beneath the directory 'TestResults'.